# How can I pass a member function instead of a function in this situation?

Tags: c++, oop, typedef, pointer-to-member

I am using an object within a class for its functionalities. The header of this object's class definition contains a typedef, then the class declaration :

```
typedef void (*Foo)(int arg);
class Bar
{private : double func(Foo f){};}
```

In my class, I want to create a member function to pass it to func :

```
class myClass
{
private : 
    Bar bar;
    void my_func(int arg);
    void my_caller();
};
```

In the .cpp :

```
void myClass::my_caller()
    {
        bar.func(&myClass::my_func);
    }
```

which returns an error "no matching function for call to Bar::func...".
My understanding is that the type used in the typedef is not "pointer to member function" but "pointer to function". I think I have to change this typedef to change this, but I don't know how.

I am an absolute beginner at C++, so I might be way off track here.

EDIT :

I understand the change I have to bring to the typedef to make a pointer to member function instead. The problem is that this typedef is in a distinct header file, so the compiler returns "'myClass' has not been declared".

Instead, I am going to look into functors and the std::function library.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is.

Comment: The typedef is a pointer to function, not pointer to member function, beside that I don't see the reason why you want to pass a pointer to member function, why not pass an instance of the class?

Comment: I've edited the title to mention what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The answer to your title is: You can't.

Comment: But the typedef is in the Bar class header file, and I don't know how to write it to take in account the class of the member function.

Comment: Not even by modifying the typedef?

Comment: In general, things get easier if you use `std::function` instead of function pointers.

Comment: @Jans my understanding is that would require me to alter the .cpp of the Bar class, which I don't want to do because it would take time and the class would become too specific to this application.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a function and a pointer to a member function are two different things.  Because the function in question is a member of `myClass`, the correct function pointer type is:

```
typedef void (myClass::*Foo)(int arg);
```